# Riak: query array of 2i through Map Reduce

Tags: mapreduce, riak

Can I query an array of secondary indexes in a Map Reduce job in Riak, instead of just the one key? I want to do something like this:

```
"inputs": {
    "bucket": myBycket,
        "index": "myIndex",
        "key": key + " OR " + key + " OR " + key
    },
    "query": [{
        "map": {
            "language":"javascript",
            "name":"Riak.mapValuesJson"
        }
    }]
}
```

But I have not found any support for it. The keys are in no particular order, so I don't think that I can use ranged queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly handle this with Map Reduce.  If you presort your target keys, you could limit the range and possibly improve performance.

```
{
 "inputs": {
    "bucket": myBycket,
    "index": "myIndex",
    "start": firstkey,
    "end": lastkey
    },
    "query": [{
        "map": {
            "language":"javascript",
            "source":"function(v) {
                        if (v.key == "key1" || v.key == "key2") {
                           return [<<put what you want returned here>>]
                        } else {
                           return []
                        }
                      }"
        }
    }]
}
```

You should note that according to the [docs site](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/mapreduce/) javascript Map Reduce has been officially deprecated, so you may want to use Erlang functions for new development.